# Template Groups in Expression Engine

Tags: expressionengine

does anyone know how EE determines the path to a given template group for modules.  For example, I have installed a module and there are template files that it uses OUTSIDE of my templates directory that I use.

Not only am I trying to understand how this works, but also how to remove reference to that so that I can move those templates to my own directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. I'm pretty sure that sort of information would most likely exist within each module's folder. If you're using EE2.X, those folders would be within `/system/expressionengine/third_party/`. If you're using EE1.X, those folders would be within `/system/modules/`. I don't think I've come across a module that renders its own templates inside of my own before. May I ask which module you're using?